# How can I access GIMP's "Alpha to Logo" with the working functionlity it used to have?

Tags: gimp

I am trying to make a book cover that uses GIMP to create stylized text via [Cool Metal](http://docs.gimp.org/en/filters-alpha-to-logo.html). In the past it has worked, but at present I haven't been able to find any way on two current systems to specify text that is to be stylized.

How can I get the old functionality back?

Comment: I figured out my problem. I wanted File -> Create -> ... and instead pulled Alpha to Logo from under Script-Fu. The problem resolved immediately when I used File -> ...

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: Thank you, @fixer1234! I've posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem. I wanted File -> Create -> Logos... and instead had pulled Alpha to Logo from under Script-Fu. The problem resolved immediately when I used File -> ...

Comment: It's supposed to be Filters -> Alpha to Logo. Unless you run an ancient version of GIMP, maybe?